# How can I display how a website will look in another form factor?

Tags: browser

Some websites use different CSS styles to display on different systems. How can I use those style sheets to show this on another form factor? For instance, I would like to show how the screen style will look on a laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in checking free online services like [TestSize.com](http://testsize.com/) or [ViewLike.us](http://viewlike.us/), hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your user agent (with an extension in Firefox, or with the `--user-agent=` parameter when calling chromium).  This can allow you to mimic your browser as Android's browser for example.

A pretty decent list of different user agents can be found here: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php